# Problem in writing a code for conversion of source data in dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ssms

Please help in writing a code for conversion of source data in dd/mm/yyyy format.

For Example:

```
**column**
02/01/2010
2/01/2010
12/11/2010
14/12/2010
01/1/2009
1/1/2008
12/31/2006
```

This column is a combination of mm/dd/yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy.

And I need to write a syntax in select statement (case statement) to get whatever the data format is atlast it needs to be in dd/mm/yyyy format.

Comment: Is there no consistency whatsoever to the results? How could you possibly tell whether `12/11/2010` is December 11 or November 12? Is there any associated data that could help? Because, as given, I fail to see how this is possible.

Comment: How do you tell which ones are `dd/mm/yyyy` and which ones are `mm/dd/yyyy` when it is not clear from the value (both `mm` and `dd` are 12 or less)?

Comment: there are other columns with that column but those are kind of entiry different and kind of waste data....that's why I am getting headache....

Comment: I asked the same question to my manager...he told me that that's my task to figure it out and to write a statement.... and I tried a syntax....SELECT DISTINCT ISDATE(Column),column FROM xyz... you will get 0's and 1's...0's are those which are greater than number 12 that means those are the date rows....

Comment: is there any possibilites to add or write any function on the source table...means whenever it will be loaded...it will directly take as dd/mm/yyyy..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will do what you want. Once the column is in date format you can represent it in any format you want. It's not pretty though.

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
SELECT CASE WHEN ISDATE(yourColumn) = 1  THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, yourColumn)
            ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(yourColumn, 
                           CHARINDEX('/', yourColumn, 0)+1, 
                           CHARINDEX('/', yourColumn, CHARINDEX('/', yourColumn, 0)+1) - CHARINDEX('/', yourColumn, 0)) 
                 + STUFF(yourColumn, 
                         CHARINDEX('/', yourColumn, 0), 
                         CHARINDEX('/', yourColumn, CHARINDEX('/', yourColumn, 0)+1) - CHARINDEX('/', yourColumn, 0), '') )
       END
FROM yourTable
```

This is highly fragile code though. If you can not be sure that a date is in dmy or mdy format, it is very likely you will produce incorrect results.

Comment: I don't have sql server on this pc, so check for off by 1 errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot Filip...it worked...really you saved my job today...really thanks a lot...you are genius...